# how to call Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS on application level

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to show my menu when the user clicks on the power button. I'm using this code which disables system power button spinner menu but I dont want to write this code on each activity. How do I call this service which disables system dialog on application level ?

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if (!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}

/* I don't want to write above code on each activity */

import android.widget.Toast;

public class CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // Log.i("HERE", "------------------------------------HERE");
        // Toast.makeText(context, "OFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

<receiver 
    android:name="com.eurosoft.cabtreasure.receiver.CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an new Activity (call it for example *BaseActivity*) which overrides the `onWindowFocusChanged` method.

Then you can make all your other Activities that need this `onWindowFocusChanged` extend BaseActivity and you don't need to copy paste this method to all Activities

Comment: give me example please

Comment: my activities already extends base activity how to add android extend

Comment: if your Activities already extend BaseActivity then move this method into your BaseActivity class: `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) { ... }`